# How to make axis/axis2 to generate toString method for generated classes?

Tags: java, apache-axis, axis, tostring, wsdl2java

Is it possible to make **axis/axis2** to generate toString method for classes generated by **wsdl2java**? They can be created manually using IDE such as Eclipse, but they will need to be regenerated each time wsdl2java is launched.

Without this method, an output in logs for instances of this classes contains no useful data (only class name and hash). While it is possible to convert the given object into string representation via reflection methods (such as apache's `BeanUtils.describe`), this solution have bigger performance impact than dedicated toString method.

Is there a plugin or patch available, that will add such functionality to axis? Or a command-line script that can be run afterwards?

This question is aimed to both versions of axis.

I don't want to reinvent the wheel, I think this is wider issue, so propably someone has already written something like that.

Answer (score 0):

no, wsdl2java overwrite the toString method

For example : you have many java classes with toString() method, if you generate wsdl with java2wsdl, and then recreate the java classes with wsdl2java, the toString method disappeared

And also I found this :

http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/axis-java-user/200801.mbox/%3Cc688cd6d0801210406t152ea4e6u3ac583ca1ad60498@mail.gmail.com%3E

With CXF tools in eclipse you can manage this, but not axis :

http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jst.ws.cxf.doc.user%2Freference%2Fwsdl2java_tab.html